# Unable to compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, compiling, ffmpeg, pkg-config, gnutls

I am following [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) compilation guide for FFmpeg. After compiling all the required dependencies, I get the following error in the last [section](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu#FFmpeg).

```
ERROR: gnutls not found using pkg-config
```

This error occurs when I run the configure command as below :

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
  --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
  --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
  --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
  --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
  --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
  --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
  --enable-gpl \
  --enable-gnutls \
  --enable-libaom \
  --enable-libass \
  --enable-libfdk-aac \
  --enable-libfreetype \
  --enable-libmp3lame \
  --enable-libopus \
  --enable-libvorbis \
  --enable-libvpx \
  --enable-libx264 \
  --enable-libx265 \
  --enable-nonfree
```

I am compiling FFmpeg on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In the `ffbuild` directory (path : `ffmpeg_sources/ffmpeg/ffbuild/`), inspecting the `config.log` gives more info on the error message :

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lunistring
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: gnutls not found using pkg-config
```

With help from ffmpeg's [IRC channel](http://ffmpeg.org/contact.html), installing the `libunistring-dev` package fixed the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install libunistring-dev
```

Comment: Hardly makes sense as one normally doesn't need libunistring-dev. The option `--pkg-config-flags="--static"` is what causes this.., not clear on value of that option, see none here.

Comment: I've just had this same error (on Debian 10.4) and installing libunistring-dev solved the problem for me too.

Comment: @doug - This is on the default compile command line from ffmpeg compile instructions: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: I understand it's in the guide. The configure option was added 5 yrs ago with no comment (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu?action=diff&version=107) . Now it needs a dep installed that isn't part of the guide. As far as option, it serves no purpose in this particular build/install of 3 binaries. No practical need for..

Comment: Thanks. This was the problem. Once i installed libunistring dev headers it compiled.

Comment: @doug Old Q/A I haven't seen before. I don't remember why `--pkg-config-flags="--static"` was added or why no comment was left (laziness?). IIRC, something to do with x265? Maybe I'll look into it. Haven't touched the guide much in a long time but made a few minor changes and cleanups today.

Answer (score 4):

The other solutions didn't work for me, although I'm on Debian not Ubuntu. For me the solution was:

```
apt install libgnutls28-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that guide does not work correctly on any Ubuntu build since at least 16.04. The simplest method to solve this problem I've found is to first install the default Ubuntu package and then generate your custom script. Prior to running your ffmpeg compile script, install the default package from official Ubuntu repository of the library that ffmpeg is complaining about:

`apt install -y gnutls`

The root cause many of these library issues and Package Config appears to be often related to C/C++ syntax that is incorrect in the library source files. This has been an issue (and continues to be one) for several ffmpeg dependencies in Ubuntu, such as [VLC's x265 library](https://github.com/m-ab-s/media-autobuild_suite/issues/632). The problem is compounded by [BitBucket's recent decision](https://bitbucket.org/blog/sunsetting-mercurial-support-in-bitbucket) to discontinue Mercurial support, including their decision to shutdown its forums, which removed several related discussions and solutions from the Internet. :(

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when building on an HPC (SLURM). The problem turned out to be an old system gcc version (4.8.0). The error disappeared after I loaded gcc 12.2.0 (module load gcc/12.2.0). Note that HPC users don't have sudo access and I've been using Anaconda libgnutls for this purpose.